# android, why say var is null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a extended class, in class have a var, I define this by value, but say this is null !!!!

```
public class CalendarCell extends TextView
{

    public static final String TAG = "CalendarCell";

    protected ArrayList<Integer> cellStates = new ArrayList<>();

public CalendarCell(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public CalendarCell(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CalendarCell(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int states)
{
    int newStatesSize = cellStates.size();  // Error here (null)
    if (newStatesSize > 0)
    {

        ...
    }
    else
    {
        return super.onCreateDrawableState(states);
    }
}

public void resetStates()
{
    cellStates.clear();
}

public void addState(int state)
{
    if(!cellStates.contains(state))
        cellStates.add(state);
    }
}
```

I defined 'cellStates' by value.but say this is null. Why???

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at yaran.CalendarSection.ViewSection.CalendarCell.onCreateDrawableState(CalendarCell.java:44)
```

Comment: did you try making cellState static?

Comment: Please edit and show the full stack trace of the exception. I wonder if this is actually being called from the super class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Make `cellStates` final like so:

```
protected final ArrayList<Integer> cellStates = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I add final, but I get error so

Comment: @ali It's pretty much impossible, a final field can't be changed and you're initializing it in declaration. There must be something else in the code that's not working.

Comment: When i add blow code ,its resolve problem.

if(cellStates == null)
 cellStates = new ArrayList<>();
 
 but for increment speed i want remove this pice

Comment: @ali You must be missing something. Try debugging the code and checking for value assignation to your field.